# strsplit: undefined function for input type 'char'

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array, split

I have a <20x1> cell array and each of them stores some data in the form of a string (as it appears to me!!!). I want to access each element of the cell as an individual string and split is in words.

The cell array I have is <20x1> cell array and to access each element as a cell I am using a for loop.

```
for i=1:20
    line=newline{i}
end
```

It shows me a all the elements within the array. Now since line is a string, I apply strsplit function to retrieve the words in the string.

```
for i=1:20
   words(i,:)=strsplit(line)
end
```

This gives me an error message :

```
??? Undefined function or method 'strsplit' for input
arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==> chk at 15
words=strsplit(newline{i})
```

can anyone explain me where I am wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a few things to clarify, what is the output of the following commands: `s = newline{1}; whos newline s; which -all strsplit`. Also remember that the output of `strsplit` will be a cell array

Comment: The output of the command is the string in the first cell of newline:`ans =

YELLOW SMALL STRETCH ADULT T` I need to extract these words in an array

Comment: yes but thats still not enough info, you see MATLAB might print a string and a cell array containing a string very similarly, thats why I asked you to post the exact output of those commands... Also `strsplit` might be shadowed by some variable in your workspace with the same name or a completely different function/script.

Comment: I posted the exact output. I copied the output from the command window and just entered here. And there are no variables in my workspace with the same name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My guess is that you're using a `version` of Matlab prior to R2013a. Despite the fact that they are generic functions and should have bee added ages ago, [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) were only [added in this most recent version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btr4jsl-1).

There are several ways you can get around not having access to `strsplit` if all you want to do is split a string into words. If all of your whitespaces are simple spaces you can just use [`strread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strread.html) like this:

```
strread(line,'%s','delimiter',' ')
```

However, [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) should be more robust:

```
textscan(line,'%s')
```

Using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) should also be robust, but will likely be slower:

```
regexp(line,'\s+','split')
```

All of these return outputs as cell arrays of strings (your words), just like `strsplit`. The output from `textscan` is transposed relative to the others.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I am using Matlab R2010a. And thanks..strread works just the way I wanted. :)

Comment: Matlab [recommends](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strread.html) using textscan over strsplit.

Comment: @UtsavSinha: your link is to the documentation for **`strread`**. This question and answer are about `strsplit`, a quite different function.

Comment: Thanks @horchler for pointing it out. I wanted to say `strread` instead of `strsplit`