# MATLAB reading all numbers from a string

Tags: matlab, parsing

I'm trying to read an unknown number of numeric values from a string.

For example:

```
line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266'
```

I tried `sscanf` but it requires I know how many numbers are in the string ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extract integer numbers from the strings, you can use a regular expression:

1. To get the numbers as a cell array of strings:

   ```
   >> line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266';
   >> regexp(line,'(?<!\d)(\d)+(?!\d)','match')
   ans = 
       '3'    '5'    '12'    '15'    '266'
   ```
2. To get the numbers as a numeric vector:

   ```
   >> str2double(regexp(line,'(?<!\d)(\d)+(?!\d)','match'))
   ans =
        3     5    12    15   266
   ```

Answer (score 6):

You can use simply [`isstrprop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html).

```
line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266'
line(isstrprop(line, 'digit'))
```

You extract numbers from the string:

```
line =

bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266


ans =

351215266
```

Comment: Thank you @Kamtal again!. I had better answers (:

Comment: @Kamtal - I hadn' t known too until a few weeks ago. It should be known because it is a powerful function I think..

Comment: I wasn't aware of `isstrprop` either.  Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

If your strings always have a separator like the colon (`':'`) between the letters and the numbers, you can use [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to extract the part of the string with just the numbers, which will be faster than using regular expressions:

```
line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266';
numstr = strsplit(line,':');
```

Then you can use [`sscanf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) to extract the digits as an array of doubles:

```
nums = sscanf(numstr{2},'%u') % Assuming digits are always unsigned, if not use %d
```

If you're using R2012b or older, you won't have `strsplit`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676330/2278029) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in 16b you can use the string class

```
line    = "bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266";
numbers = extractAfter(line,': ');
numbers = split(numbers);
numbers = double(numbers);
```

This seems to be the fastest option.

```
>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 0.088259 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.558718 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.482743 seconds.

function profFunc

    n = 1E4;

    tic;
        for i = 1:n
            line = "bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266";
            numbers = extractAfter(line,': ');
            numbers = split(numbers);
            numbers = double(numbers);
        end
    toc

    tic;
        for i = 1:n
            line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266';
            numbers = str2double(regexp(line,'(?<!\d)(\d)+(?!\d)','match'));
        end
    toc

    tic;
        for i = 1:n
            line = 'bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266';
            numstr = strsplit(line,':');
            nums = sscanf(numstr{2},'%u');
        end
    toc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is the possibility of negative or decimal numbers, the regular expression can be updated as such:

```
str2double(regexp(line,'(-?\d+\.?\d?)','match'))
```

Examples:

```
str2double(regexp('bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15 266','(-?\d+\.?\d?)','match'))
```

> ans =
>
> 3     5    12    15   266

```
str2double(regexp('bla bal bli : 3 5 12 15.4 -266','(-?\d+\.?\d?)','match'))
```

> ans =
>
> 3.0000    5.0000   12.0000   15.4000 -266.0000